# Finding distance of two locations in HTML?

Tags: php, html

I already know that I am supposed to use Google Maps Services to get the long and lat of the address. My question is how can I determine the distance between two locations. I need this as a project I'm working on (Lostr) that can help find lost people by searching through its database (and allowing submittions using Foundr). Its a great idea and I'm stuck at finding the distance. Help?

Comment: Are you sure HTML is the right flag here? What language are you using? How are you accessing the maps service?

Comment: Oops I am using php but it contains mostly HTML code.

Comment: I found an online tutorial on how.

Comment: Got it. Well since HTML is declarative markup and not really a programming language, you're not going to be making any calls to the Maps API using HTML. I'd slap on the PHP tag.

Comment: What about javascript instead of PHP?

Comment: I used php to register the data onto a server

Answer (score 0):

You're required to use the [Google Maps Distance Api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/start), this api allows you to calculate distances using pure Javascript emmbeded in your HTML. You need to get registered in google console to [get an api key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/get-api-key) too.

This is a response to a api call via JS:

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "New York, NY, USA" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Washington, DC, USA" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "225 mi",
                  "value" : 361715
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "3 hours 49 mins",
                  "value" : 13725
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```